# how to filter CSV files using batch

Tags: batch, csv

How to filter CSV files using batch as below:

I have a file with 7 columns separated by '~'

I need to check if column number 4 is in (456,987,654,123,456), If yes than append the whole row to existing csv file

[this link may help, but i dont know how to modify it to use it](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=68806)

Comment: First, ~ isn't a comma, so I don't think this is technically a Comma Separated Values (CSV) case.  It is, however, a fixed delimiter issue.  Are you sure this isn't a homework exercise?

Comment: Installed LogParser 

and run below:

logparser -i:CSV "SELECT * into C:\Battest\Final.csv FROM C:\Battest\test.csv  where mbrno = 123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark. I haven't tested it:

```
:: ------------------ BAT start here -----------
@echo off
del c:\Total.csv
Del c:\Final.csv

Type c:\BATTEST\*.CSV > c:\Total.csv

FOR /F "eol=- delims=~ tokens=1-5,6,7*" %%1 IN ( c:\Total.CSV ) DO IF %%4 EQ 456 ECHO %%1 %%2 %%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 >> c:\Final.csv
FOR /F "eol=- delims=~ tokens=1-5,6,7*" %%1 IN ( c:\Total.CSV ) DO IF %%4 EQ 987 ECHO %%1 %%2 %%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 >> c:\Final.csv
FOR /F "eol=- delims=~ tokens=1-5,6,7*" %%1 IN ( c:\Total.CSV ) DO IF %%4 EQ 654 ECHO %%1 %%2 %%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 >> c:\Final.csv
FOR /F "eol=- delims=~ tokens=1-5,6,7*" %%1 IN ( c:\Total.CSV ) DO IF %%4 EQ 123 ECHO %%1 %%2 %%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 >> c:\Final.csv

:: ------------------ Bat end here --------------------
```

A few assumptions this makes:

- your file has 8 fields in it, never more.
- your source files are located in C:\BATTEST

If it works, your output file will be in C:\Final.csv. If your file has fewer fields in it, then there are a few things that would need to be changed.